# PDO MySQL Update not working correctly on edit page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A 'quiz' currently contains a quiz id, name, description and topic (from a topic table).

I am wanting to setup a simple 'Edit Quiz' page.

The problem is - if a quiz is called 'Quiz1' and I change the quiz name on the edit page to 'Quiz2', once the save button is clicked it will revert back to 'Quiz1' and not stored.

I have setup an echo as shown in the code to check that they are actually getting stored, after the save button is clicked it would show 'Quiz1' but this value is not stored in my database. The SQL Has been tested on PhpMyAdmin and seems to work too.

PHP Code:

```
<? if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $id = $_POST['qzid'];
    $qzname = $_POST['qzname'];
    $qzdesc = $_POST['qzdesc'];
    $ctname = $_POST['ctname'];

    $checkQuiz = $db->prepare("SELECT qz_name FROM quizzes WHERE qz_name = :qz_name");
    $checkQuiz->execute(array(':qz_name' => $qzname));


    $qzChanged = "Quiz details updated successfully";
    $sql = "UPDATE quizzes SET  `qz_name` = :qzname, `qz_desc` = :qzdesc WHERE `quizzes`.`id` = :qzid";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':qzname' => $qzname, ':qzdesc' => $qzdesc, ':qzid' => $id));

    echo $qzname, $qzdesc; //THIS RETURNS THE CHANGED VALUES

    }?>
```

HTML Code:

```
<form action="edit_quiz.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="qzid" id="qzid" value=""/>
<!-- selection box -->
<p>Topic Name:
    <select class="form-control" name="ctname" id="ctname">
        <?php
        while ($tresult = $stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "<option>" . $tresult["ct_name"] . "</option>";

        }
        ?>
    </select>
</p>
<p>Quiz Name: <input type="text" name="qzname" value="<?php echo $row['qz_name']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Quiz Description: <textarea name="qzdesc" value=""/><?php echo $row['qz_desc']; ?> </textarea></p>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/> <a class="btn" href="quizzes.php">Back</a>
```

Please note this code has been simplified.
Any help I would appreciate very much thanks!

Comment: Do you need "localhost" in your update statement? is that actually the name of your database? Since you don't specify a DB name in the select statement I would try removing that first

Comment: Sorry that doesn't make a difference, just my inconsistency! (updated my code to avoid confusion)

Comment: how about the qzid hidden input, it doesn't seem to have a value, so it wouldn't know which row to update

Comment: @Trey you're right that isn't needed, however I have removed and it still doesn't update but the echo still works perfectly.

Comment: right but the update relies on the "where id=" clause, try echoing the id

Comment: Thanks @Trey it was the id, it had no value set, therefore SQL wouldn't update as the id wasn't posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not posting the id it looks like.

Is your database named localhost, otherwise remove that part.

Comment: Thank you!   The  <input type="hidden" name="qzid" id="qzid" value=""/> statement needed a value (id) to be posted. Don't know how I missed this.